# How to implement a short-circuit with IO monad in Scala

Tags: scala, monads

I use a standard IO monad.

And at some point, i need to shortcircuit. On a given condition, i don't want to run the following ios.

Here is my solution, but I found it too verbose and not elegant :

```
  def shortCircuit[A](io: IO[A], continue: Boolean) =
    io.map(a => if (continue) Some(a) else None)

  for {
    a <- io
    b <- shortCircuit(io, a == 1)
    c <- shortCircuit(io, b.map(_ == 1).getOrElse(false))
    d <- shortCircuit(io, b.map(_ == 1).getOrElse(false))
    e <- shortCircuit(io, b.map(_ == 1).getOrElse(false))
  } yield …
```

For example, for 3rd, 4th and 5th line, I need to repeat the same condition.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Do you need the values of `a`, `b`, `c`, etc., or do you just care about the effects? `OptionT[IO, ?]` kind of sounds like what you're looking for, but it would just give you a `None` if it short-circuits.

Comment: I need these values : as condition for short-circuit and also in the yield clause.

Comment: io has side effect, so the run method may return a different value after each call.

Comment: Silly me, I misread the `for` as part of `shortCircuit` because of indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually short-circuited anything there.  You are still running the IOs; you just don't capture the values.

Also, the standard IO monad doesn't define `filter` (or `withFilter`), so you can't use guards in your for-comprehension.

Now, if you want just what you've said (same logic, just more DRY), you can always assign a temporary variable in the for comprehension:

```
for {
  a <- io
  b <- shortCircuit(io, a == 1)
  continue = b.map(_ == 1).getOrElse(false)
  c <- shortCircuit(io, continue)
  d <- shortCircuit(io, continue)
  e <- shortCircuit(io, continue)
} yield …
```

But if you actually want to short-circuit, you will have to break apart the cases in some way.  Here's one possibility, assuming you just want to pack everything into an array so the return type is simple, and your `IO` companion object has an apply method that you can use to create something that just returns a value:

```
io.flatMap(a =>
  if (a == 1) IO(() => Array(a))
  else io.flatMap(b =>
    if (b == 1) IO(() => Array(a,b))
    else for {
      c <- io
      d <- io
      e <- io
    } yield Array(a,b,c,d,e)
  )
)
```

If your return types are more complicated, you may have to work harder with specifying types.

FWIW, it is worth noting the penalty that you pay for keeping things wrapped in monads; without, the same logic would be (for example):

```
io() match {
  case 1 => Array(1)
  case a => io() match {
    case 1 => Array(a, 1)
    case b => Array(a, b, io(), io(), io())
  }
}
```

And if you allow returns, you get:

```
val a = io()
if (a == 1) return Array(a)
val b = io()
if (b == 1) return Array(a, b)
Array(a, b, io(), io(), io())
```

It's also possible in principle to decorate the IO monad with extra methods that help out a bit, but the standard `withFilter` won't work so you won't be able to use the for-comprehension syntactic sugar.

Comment: Wdyt about adding this method on IO :
  def withGuard[B](f: A => IO[B], guard : A => Boolean, builder: A => B): IO[B] =
    new IO[B] {
      def run = {
        val a = self.run
        if (guard(a)) f(a).run else builder(a)
      }
    }

Comment: @YannMoisan - Well, it really depends on the signature of the methods.  Short-circuiting early tends to change the method signature, which you can't do with filter.  I'm not sure at a glance whether `withGuard` will work, but it's not very hard to find out if you make your IO be printlns and try it out!